# How to quit or relaunch an android app when user is not interacting with app

Tags: android

i want to update a table in my app database which is only possible when i relaunch the app. So, is it possible to quit or relaunch the android app programmatically, after a certain interval of time when user is not interacting with app or user has put the app in back ground.

Comment: Why do you need to relaunch app to update DB? Any specific reason?

Comment: When you say you want to update a DB, do you mean update a column, or you mean add a column/change a column name/etc...? Updating a field WITHIN a column of a table doesn't require a restart. However, a change to the table name, etc... does require a restart,etc... and you will also need to increment the DB version I believe.

Comment: because on relaunch of the app, user has to go through  login process where i am checking the user status on my server wether it is activated or deactivated then i saved/update it in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just extends this base activty instead of AppCompatActivity

```
public class BaseAppCompactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       //activity restart this timeout
        public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 14400000; // 5 min = 5 * 60 * 1000 ms


        private Handler disconnectHandler = new CustomHandler();

        private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Perform any required operation on disconnect
                finishAffinity();
            }
        };

        public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
            disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
            disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        }

        public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
            disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserInteraction(){
            resetDisconnectTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            System.out.println("Base Activity Resume called");
            super.onResume();
            resetDisconnectTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            System.out.println("Base Activity Stop called");
            super.onStop();
            stopDisconnectTimer();
        }
        static class CustomHandler extends Handler {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```